# How to have a dynamic index of a Python list

Tags: python

I am looking for a solution to have a conditional dynamic list index in Python.

My current approach (abstracted) which does **not** increment the index by 1 if `Foo == Bar`:

```
# Considered list

list = [
     'itemShiftZero',
     'itemShiftOne'
]


# Basic if-else to define the shift conditionally

if Foo == Bar:
    shift = 1
else:
    shift = 0


# Transfer logic to the list index

item = list[0 + shift]
```

Note: Due to my codes logic, there is currently no option to make both parameters variable (otherwise I could have set the logic before the index part to just use the resulting variable as list index)

Comment: What you've named list and "considered dic" is neither a list nor a dictionary, it's a set. It's not clear to me what you're actually asking here.

Comment: meant list, sorry

Comment: And what's the *problem* with the code you've posted?

Comment: `0` is the *additive identity*. What is the point of adding it to anything?

Comment: The issues solved  itself after @jonrsharpe highlighted that I refered to a wrong object... I used curly brackets in my code rather than [], can be closed.. Thanks nevertheless

Comment: `item = list[1] if Foo == Bar else list[0]` seems clearer.

Comment: In that case just delete this post.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine logically, **EXCEPT**:

- You named your `list` as `list`, thus contaminating the namespace. PLEASE NEVER name your list as `list`. I have renamed it to **`items`**.
- You must define variables `foo` and `bar` before you use them.
- Although this was not the cause of your error, as a variable naming convention: *Variable names should be written in small letters ([PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id34)) separated with underscore*.
- But as @Booboo mentioned, `0` being additive identity, you could simply use `item = items[shift]`.

### My suggestion

Now having said all this, if I were you, I would just do this:

```py
item = items[1 if (foo==bar) else 0]
```

### Correction to your code

```py
# list renamed to items
items = [
     'itemShiftZero',
     'itemShiftOne'
]

# define foo and bar
foo = bar = True

# Basic if-else to define the shift conditionally

if foo == bar:
    shift = 1
else:
    shift = 0


# Transfer logic to the list index

item = items[0 + shift] # list renamed to items
print(item)
```

**Output**:

```
itemShiftOne
```